# Parsing JSON Object Array

Tags: java, arrays, json, object, parsing

I am very new to using Jquery and Json. I have a servlet that is returning an array of JSONObject's ( basically a JSONArray object ).

I am trying to parse this array within JavaScript and am running into trouble here.
I have a  javascript variable "var result" that gets the result from the servlet and I am trying to parse it as result[0].uniqueId for example to get the value of uniqueId sent from the server. But this does not seeem to work.

Below is the Java servlet code snippet to show what gets sent to the javascript client.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    JSONArray arrayObj = new JSONArray();
             List<Folder> children =getFolders(request,response);
             Iterator itr = children.iterator();
             while(itr.hasNext())
             {
                 Folder folder = (Folder) itr.next();
                 obj = new JSONObject();
                 obj.put("uniqueId", folder.getUniqueId());
                 obj.put("folderName", folder.getFolderName());
                 obj.put("size", folder.getSize());
                 obj.put("modified", folder.getModified());

                 arrayObj.add(obj);
             }
            out = response.getWriter();
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            out.println(arrayObj);           
}
```

This is the jquery code snippet

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'getFolders',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'uniqueID=' + uniqueID ,
            //console.log(data);
            success: function(result) {  
                //parse result
                        alert("JSON result "+ result[0].uniqueId);

                }//end success
    });
```

Please advice as how to parse the result.

Thanks
Deepthi

Comment: BTW, you should not return JSON arrays. The default array constructor is overridable in javascript so returning arrays allow and external website to call your api and get data back.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Now my question is in my servlet i am iterating a list which contains "Folder" Objects. Each folder object i am converting it to JSON Object. So, I will be having multiple JSON Objects. if i don't use any JSON array how can i get multiple JSON Objects to the client. And another question is, If i suppose get multiple JSON objects from the server. how do i parse it and get the values .Please advice me 
 I need to parse multiple JSON objects in the Success function in the Jquery ajax call.

Comment: Thank You all, I was able to figure it out my Problem.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the [dataType option](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax) to the type of data you're expecting back from the server:

```
$.ajax({
              dataType: 'json',
              url: 'getFolders',
              type: 'POST',
              data: 'uniqueID=' + uniqueID ,
              //console.log(data);
              success: function(result) {  
              //parse result
                    alert("JSON result "+ result[0].uniqueId);

              }//end success
        });
```

Comment: Yes, jQuery ignores the `"application/json"` Content type in the response for some reason, so you need to specify `dataType`. IMO it's a bug (at a minimum it's inconsistent with how it acknowledges content types of `"application/xml"` or `"text/html"`).